# fixed header goes behind text, and only sometimes over

Tags: javascript, html, css

My fixed header at www.tdgordon.com tends to go behind the content on each page ( most noticeable on mobile) and occasionally it will land in front, but go behind content again as soon as I start scrolling. I have tried adding z-index values, but due to the fact that a couple of pages are layered with transparent color backgrounds and photos, i haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your account is suspended. Can you give us an example so we can help? a Jsfiddle would be great

Comment: hi, I can see you are new.You aren't really supposed to include your website address in the question. Can you edit the question and paste in the code from your HTML and CSS so we can reproduce the problem. Post in the minimum that you need. A link to an uploaded photo would be helpful, or paste you code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and post the link here.

Comment: Sorry guys! I didn't know that couldn't post my website. The link should work now, though. And I will post the files when I get back to my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in relation to a sticky header?

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
```

The z-index property can go into the millions, but really sorting out the layering of the photos should be a priority.

Comment: Also, how would i "sort out" the laying?

Comment: Glad to hear it!
And don't worry too much about 'sorting it out' - since I didn't see the link I just assumed that you had pictures scattered throughout z-space.